# VB6 Project restore from Icon tray

Tags: vb6

I have a VB6 Project I want to start on windows startup and automatically go into Taskbar Icon tray.
I have achieve this with the code. but after it goes into icon tray I am not able to retrieve it / show my form.
like how to right click on icon tray and open or close form from there.

like in icon tray I right click on icon and it ask open or close if I click on open it will show form as it is. and on close it will kill app.

```
Private Sub Form_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    ' Show the form when mouse moves over the tray icon
    If Button = vbLeftButton Then
        Me.WindowState = vbNormal
        Me.Show
    End If
End Sub
```

I tried this but no success.

Comment: Is that all your code?  What have you programmed so far that has to do with the tray logic?

Comment: Does your app have a menu defined?  You will use that as the popup menu when right-clicking on the tray icon.  The popup menu will have all the options your app needs including an item for showing the form.